# How to reduce the height by 150 from the top and bottom?

Tags: javascript

There is a fixed height, say 1000. If the screen height becomes less than 1000, then you need to remove 150 pixels from this height from the top and bottom. How can this even be done on pure js?

Comment: Please post the relavent code details with your attempts so that someone can help you where you are stuck

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css media queries for this.

> for example lets say your code is
>
> ```
> <div class='container'>
> <p> This is a paragraph </p>
> </div>
> ```

css

```
.container{
   margin-top:150px;
   height:1000px
   margin-bottom:150px;
}

 @media (max-height: 1000px) { 
    .container{
        margin-top:0px;
        height:1000px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
     }
 }
```

https://codepen.io/husnuljahneer/pen/poWQPgX